# Generate Java classes for web service

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I am attempting to write a web client to access a web service; I out of every tool I have tried (CXF, JAX-WS, JAXB, Axis) only Visual Studio 2012 and soapUI are able to access the web service. For the Java generated classes the API is incorrect, there is no way to pass in the Authentication object. soupUI can call the web services and a CSharp program works fine. But my boss expects Java.

Anybody know what library soupUI is using, is it something I haven't tried or is it proprietary? Or anyone know how to hit this web service with Java and have it work?

Comment: What kind of authentication do you have?

Comment: Sometimes the authentication is by configuration and not in code. Hence it would help to know what authentication are you expecting. Also, you can generate Axis WS artefacts from SOAPui, if that helps.